# Woocommerce: product id in the order received url

Tags: php, wordpress, url, woocommerce, orders

I would like to change the order received (thanks page) url for a new one, which includes the ordered product's ID.

Here is the code in the class-wc-order.php

```
/**
 * Generates a URL for the thanks page (order received).
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function get_checkout_order_received_url() {
    $order_received_url = wc_get_endpoint_url( 'order-received', $this->get_id(), wc_get_page_permalink( 'checkout' ));

    if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_force_ssl_checkout' ) || is_ssl() ) {
        $order_received_url = str_replace( 'http:', 'https:', $order_received_url );
    }

    $order_received_url = add_query_arg( 'key', $this->get_order_key(), $order_received_url );

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_checkout_order_received_url', $order_received_url, $product, $this, $product->id );
}
```

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: What happens if multiple products are ordered?

Comment: As helgathevicking is suggesting, you need to go through order items to get the product ID as you can have many for one order… see  [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)

Comment: In 99% of cases, only 1 type of product will be ordered. This is needed because I would like to measeure the orders with Google Analytics, and  I could set it up for every product url.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/249276/how-to-change-or-add-woocommerce-thank-you-page-url-key-content) on wordpress.stackexchange.com would solve the issue

As a brief, just define the following hook:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_checkout_order_received_url','override_return_url',10,2);

function override_return_url($return_url,$order){

    //create empty array to store url parameters in 
    $sku_list = array();

    // retrive products in order
    foreach($order->get_items() as $key => $item)
    {
      $product = wc_get_product($item['product_id']);
      //get sku of each product and insert it in array 
      $sku_list['product_'.$item['product_id'] . 'sku'] = $product->get_sku();
    }
    //build query strings out of the SKU array
    $url_extension = http_build_query($sku_list);
    //append our strings to original url
    $modified_url = $return_url.'&'.$url_extension;

    return $modified_url;
}
```

Then, you can set the analytics goal to point to the destination below as a regular expression

```
\/checkout\/order-received\/\d+\/\?key=\w+&product_ID_HERE_sku=SKU_HERE
```

We can make it simpler by including only product ids:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_checkout_order_received_url','override_return_url',0,2);

function override_return_url($return_url,$order){
  $ids = array();
  foreach($order->get_items() as $key => $item)
  {
    $ids[] = $item['product_id'];
  }
  return add_query_arg('product_ids', join(',', $ids) , $return_url);
}
```

In this case, the regex would be:

`\/checkout\/order-received\/\d+\/\?key=\w+&product_ids=ID1,ID2,ID3`

Or for a single product id:

`\/checkout\/order-received\/\d+\/\?key=\w+&product_ids=[\w,]*ID[\w,]*`